# Why does one of my strings get repeated over and over again after I try

Tags: python, string, dictionary, email, formatting

I am trying to concatenate various strings together to form a message.

The ideal output looks like this:

```
The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%:\
MSFT: 0.05\
TSLA: 0.012\
AAPL: 0.019
```

Below is my code:

```python
stocks = {
    "MSFT":0.05,
    "TSLA":0.012,
    "AAPL":0.019,
}

subject = 'Opening Price Warnings'
body = 'The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%: \n'.join([f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in stocks.items()])
msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
print(msg)
```

My code is repeating the first line over and over again.
I get a message like this:\

```
MSFT: 0.05The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%:\
TSLA: 0.012The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%:\
AAPL: 0.019The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%:
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Originally, you provided a English description of the `stocks` dictionary. In order to answer your question, we need to be able to run your code, and see what the error is. Even if your code is wrong, never omit the code necessary to generate the test data. Otherwise, we have to write the code to generate the `stocks` dictionary ourselves, which only delays matter. Do prune your code, so that the example are short, but if you need a dictionary named `stocks`, then show us the code to make a small valid example of a `stocks` dictionary.

Comment: I edited your question to include code to generate an example `stocks` dictionary. However, but next time you post on stack-overflow, please include all of the necessary code that we can run your code ourselves. We need to be able to run it and see the console output for ourselves. We can't do that if the `stocks` dictionary is missing.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon thanks, i'm still learning python so this is all new to me, I thought how I wrote it it would have been enough. I will add more info in future questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in `body` you are joining the *same* initial string to *all* the entries of the for loop string.

Have just `body = 'The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%:` and make a *new* string with only the dict elements.

```
stocks = {'MSFT': 0.05, 'TSLA': 0.012}
body1 = 'The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%: \n'
body2 = '\n'.join([f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in stocks.items()])
body1 + body2
# 'The following stocks have changed with more than 0.9%: \nMSFT: 0.05\nTSLA: 0.012\nAAPL: 0.019'
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.join()` is ***NOT*** a function to concatenate two strings.

The `join` function is used to insert delimiters.
The delimiters separate elements in a container of strings.

An example is shown below:

```python
eldest_cookie_jar = [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green"
]

s = "-".join(eldest_cookie_jar)
print(s)
```

The console output is:

```
red-blue-green
```

In the above example, I used a hyphen character (`-`) as a delimiter.
All of the colors are seperated by hyphens.

The pattern is:

> `output = delimiter.join(non_delimiters)`

***non-delimiters*** are your actual data in string form.

If you want numbers seperated from eachother by commas, then convert the numbers to strings, then call `str.join()`, like so:

```python
stryng = ",".join(numbers)
```

If you imagine making a sandwhich, then we have:

```python
buns = ["(top bun)", "(bottom bun)"]
meat = "(meat)"

result = meat.join(buns)
print(result)
# "(top bun)(meat)(bottom bun)"
```

Below yet even more examples; included for the sake of being ridiculously exhaustive:

```python
eldest_cookie_jar = [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green"
]

# It is important to convert data to strings
# before using `str.join()` to delimit the data
#
# `map(str, data)` will convert each element
# of `data` into a string.
#

youngest_cookie_jar = tuple(map(str, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]))

meta_container = [
    eldest_cookie_jar,
    youngest_cookie_jar
]

delims = [
    ", ",
    "...",
    ":--:",
    " ",
    "   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   "
]

for container in meta_container:
    for delimiter in delims:
        result = delimiter.join(container)
        beginning = "\n----------\n"
        print(result, end=beginning)
```

The console output is:

```
red, blue, green
----------
red...blue...green
----------
red:--:blue:--:green
----------
red blue green
----------
red   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   blue   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   green
----------
0.1, 0.2, 0.3
----------
0.1...0.2...0.3
----------
0.1:--:0.2:--:0.3
----------
0.1 0.2 0.3
----------
0.1   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   0.2   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   0.3
----------
```